# javascript stream wrapper, intercept JS file contents

Tags: javascript

In PHP there's a function called **stream_wrapper_register**. With that i can get the file contents of every PHP file that is about to be included. So that basically gives me control over the 'code' that will get parsed.

I was wondering if there's something like this in javascript too? So suppose i include my file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myfile.js"></script>
```

My code in that file then sets up the stream wrapper (suppose this is available in JS too). Now i want to be able to get the file contents of every other javascript file that will be included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/somefile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/someotherfile.js"></script>
```

But this ofcourse must happen before before the browser actually executes those files.

So is there a way to intercept that somehow?

Comment: You'll need to do this on the server. You could set up a mod_rewrite rule (if you're using Apache) to catch every JavaScript request, then route it through a PHP file that does what you need it to, then outputs the JS.

Comment: @JamWaffles Yes that's unfortunately the only way i could think off too. But i really want a javascript solution. Hopefully there's still an answer out there :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax("/path/to/javascript.js").done(function(source) {
    eval(transmogrifySourceCode(source));
});
```

I used the jQuery syntax because AJAX-style gets are much easier that way, and you'll have to provide your own `transmogrifySourceCode` function to edit the source before you load it.

I do wonder why you'd want to do, that, though. You should be in full control over your input source, so why not just excise the code you don't want on the server?

Comment: I guess this is the closest i can get

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Alone for security reasons you won't be allowed to get every script's content.

For Opera, there is a special [`BeforeScript` event](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/specs/#userjsevent) which [can be listened to](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/specs/#evlistener) from local user scripts.

So there is no (good) way to detect (dynamically added) `<script>` elements in a page and prevent them from loading and executing a script. Yet you could load the script files by ajax, respecting the same-origin-policy (!), and evaling their modified contents as @DavidEllis suggested.

Elsewise, you need to proxy all script inclusions over your server and modify them there.