# Basics of script pre-processing

Tags: javascript, preprocessor

I have this code:

```
<script id="toModify" >
Invalid javascript that will cause errors
</script>

<script>
var s=document.getElementById("toModify");
s.innerHTML="alert('Hi')";
</script>
```

And it doesn't work.

I know there is at least two things I need to do so that it works:

- Prevent the first script to run the first time.
- Once modified, re-run the first script.

How can I do these things? Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Can you tell us why you want/need to do that? I'm sure there is a better solution to your original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a `type` attribute so that the browser doesn't execute a script:

  ```
  <script id="toModify" type="text/x-custom-whatever">...</script>
  ```
- Just `eval()` the code to execute it.

Of course, dynamically generating code is fraught with peril; be very careful that you're not introducing security holes.

Comment: @Mageek: This is not an instance to declare "but `eval` is evil".  There is absolutely **zero difference** between using `eval` and inserting a string into a newly created `<script>` element -- other than the DOM method being [tremendously slower](http://jsperf.com/eval-vs-script-dom-insertion).  Either way, you're executing dynamically generated code.  The DOM-insertion method is just doing it without using a four-letter keyword.

Comment: @Mageek, well it depends on the way you create the benchmark test ;) if you cache the references then the DOM insertion is faster than eval .. http://jsperf.com/eval-vs-script-dom-insertion/2

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: not in Chrome or IE.

Comment: @josh3736, yep indeed !! A good peek under the hood on changes between browsers ...

Answer (score 1):

Setting a type to the script that is <strike>different to the "text/javascript"</strike> not-supported will make the script to not get processed.

so `<script id="toModify" type="text/unprocessed">...</script>`

then you can create a new element of type script set its innerHTML and append it in the document..

something like

```
var s = document.getElementById("toModify");
var processed = document.createElement('script'); // create a new script element

processed.innerHTML = "alert('Hi')"; // or do something with the s.innerHTML
document.body.insertBefore(processed, document.body.firstChild); // add the new element to the body, it gets executed immediately..
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/GG7cT/

Answer (score -1):

You can't. The first script will always run first. Even when it had a `defer` attribute, I'm not sure whether you would be able to change its contents.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10805666/1048572).

Comment: This is incorrect.  By adding an unrecognized `type` attribute, browsers will ignore a `<script>` block's content.  You can then fetch the content of that block later.

Comment: Of course, but if he could modify the source of his page whw would he need that at all? Having the code he posted, it's impossible.

Comment: A common use is to include a HTML templating language in a `<script>` element.  You later grab the template source from the element and use it to render data (that is usually fetched via AJAX).

Comment: Yes, I know about these. I think the OP tried to "correct" an other script which is already in the page by a subsequent script - which *is* impossible.